# Can the result of DENSE_RANK () be used in a SUM of the current select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, window-functions, dense-rank

1. I have a table which holds daily hours Mon -Sun, I have a function which calculates and returns the weekly total. I sum these based on the current week and partition by the element_id and start_date calling the result WEEK_HRS_TOTAL.

This results in a total for each week.

```
SUM(GENERATED_FOR_WEEK(et.START_DATE, et.END_DATE, elm.element_id, MON...SUN_ )) OVER(PARTITION BY elm.element_id, et.START_DATE)as WEEK_HRS_TOTAL
```

2. I also have in this select another sum function exactly like the one above except this sum is to total the WEEK_HRS_TOTAL for the year. Thus resulting in a cultivate running total for each entry. However in this sum I partition by the elm.Name, and sub element name elm.SubName and return as HRS_TOTAL_YEAR

   SUM(GENERATED_FOR_YEAR(et.START_DATE, et.END_DATE, elm.element_id, MON...SUN_ )) OVER(PARTITION BY elm.Name, elm.SubName)as HRS_TOTAL_YEAR

The result of this works as expected however the issue is the total will be displayed for each record and need it to display as a running total.

Example:

```
ELM NAME    ELM SUB_NAME       WEEK_HRS_TOTAL       HRS_TOTAL_YEAR 
DOOR          KNOB                  12                  37
DOOR          KNOB                  23                  37
DOOR          KNOB                  2                   37
DOOR          PAINT                 3                   10
DOOR          PAINT                 4                   10
DOOR          PAINT                 3                   10
```

I would have tried to use

DENSE_RANK to produce a column based on the elm.SubName giving

```
ELM NAME    ELM SUB_NAME       WEEK_HRS_TOTAL  RANK     HRS_TOTAL_YEAR 
DOOR          KNOB                  12           1       37
DOOR          KNOB                  23           1       37
DOOR          KNOB                  2            1       37
DOOR          PAINT                 3            2       10
DOOR          PAINT                 4            2       10
DOOR          PAINT                 3            2       10
```

Is there a way to get my HRS_TOTAL_YEAR to use the RANK column rather than the ELM SUB_NAME to create the running total resulting in the following?

```
ELM NAME    ELM SUB_NAME       WEEK_HRS_TOTAL  RANK     HRS_TOTAL_YEAR 
DOOR          KNOB                  12           1       12
DOOR          KNOB                  23           1       35
DOOR          KNOB                  2            1       37
DOOR          PAINT                 3            2       3
DOOR          PAINT                 4            2       7
DOOR          PAINT                 3            2       10


Create or Replace "WEEK_HRS_TOTAL" (p_start_date et.start_date%type,
                                    p_end_date   et.end_date%type,
                                    p_elm_id     elm.element_id,
                                    p_sun_hrs    et.sun_hrs
                                    .....this continues for each day of the week) Return Number AS
lv_dollar_gen_sum number;
lv_start_date date;
lv_end_date date;
lv_rate elm.rate%type;

begin
  loop
  exit when lv_start_date >= lv_end_date;

  select r.rate into lv_rate 
  from hour_rate r 
  where r.element_id = p_element_id and
        r.start_date <= lv_start_date and
        r.end_date  > lv_start_date;

  lv_dollar_gen_sum := lv_dollar_gen_sum + (p_mon_hrs * lv_rate);
  lv_start_date := lv_start_date + 1;
```

We do this for each day in the week and then return the result. Both functions do the same thing, however the partition for the WEEKS_HRS_TOTAL function call is based on element_id and et.start_date

While the partition for the HRS_TOTAL_YEAR is based on elm.Name, elm.SubName

Comment: If you use SUM() as an analytic function with a PARTITION BY clause but no ORDER BY clause, you get the behavior you noticed. Add an ORDER BY clause and you will get a running sum. (If you order by a column or expression that may have duplicates, you may also need a windowing clause, or add more criteria to ORDER BY.)

Comment: I will update the post with the requested.

Comment: Is it possible to declare in the order by of the partition the result of: DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY elm.Name)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add an `ORDER BY` to the `SUM()`.  However, your data does not have an obvious column:

```
SUM(GENERATED_FOR_YEAR(et.START_DATE, et.END_DATE, elm.element_id, MON...SUN_ )) OVER
        (PARTITION BY elm.Name, elm.SubName
         ORDER BY ??
        ) as HRS_TOTAL_YEAR
```

Nothing in the data you've shown has the ordering that you seem to want.

Comment: Ok, so the start date is based on a week, and I selected the week table into the selection and used the ORDER_BY as described and now I have achieved a running total. Thanks a bunch mathGuy and Gordon!